# What error type can we expect in getDerivedStateFromError()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

According to the [TypeScript definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L601) the type is `any`, whereas the related method [componentDidCatch()](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L577) receives an error of type `Error`. Why this inconsistency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current accepted answer and the React type definitions are incorrect. The exception can in fact be of any type (including `null`, `undefined`, `number`, or whatever other type). Simply try throwing some of those values from your render function and see what happens. If you want to be completely correct, you should use

```js
static getDerivedStateFromError(error: unknown) { ... }
```

and

```js
componentDidCatch(error: unknown, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo) { ... }
```

and check the type of the error in your error handling code, if necessary. For example, you could use

```js
if (error instanceof Error) { ... }
```

to check if the error really is an [Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

Answer (score 9):

Typescript has a global `Error` interface that you can use.

```
interface Error {
    stack?: string;
}
```

so you can use

```
static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
  // ...
}

componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo) {
  // ...
}
```

the `GetDerivedStateFromError` type is shown below and I think it's error type should not be of type `any`, but also of type `Error`

```
type GetDerivedStateFromError<P, S> =
        /**
         * This lifecycle is invoked after an error has been thrown by a descendant component.
         * It receives the error that was thrown as a parameter and should return a value to update state.
         *
         * Note: its presence prevents any of the deprecated lifecycle methods from being invoked
         */
        (error: any) => Partial<S> | null;
```